# Cancel incoming data from Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, unsubscribe

I have Angular input where every time its value changes I ask service to get some data about entered value. I only care about last entered input, so when user enters '1', but then erases it and enters '2' I don't care about data about previous value. I wrote something like this (I keep value of previous request in prevNr):

```
let stream,
  nr = document.querySelector('input').value;

if (status === `${nr} in progress`) {
  stream.unsubscribe();
  console.log(`subscription of ${prevNr} cancelled`)
}

status = 'in progress';
prevNr = nr;

console.log(`started subscription of ${nr}`)
stream = someService.someMethod.subscribe(() => {
  const clonedNr = nr;
  setTimeout(() => {
    status = 'done';
    console.log(`received response for ${clonedNr}`)
  }, 12000);
})
```

What I get back in console is

```
1 in progress

subscription of 1 cancelled
2 in progress

subscription of 2 cancelled
3 in progress

subscription of 3 cancelled
4 in progress

received response for 1
received response for 2
received response for 3
received response for 4
```

Right now I mock response by setTimeout(), but I can imagine situation where I receive data for input 4 before data for input 3 and as result this data will be assigned to wrong input. 
How can I omit previous requests in Observable? Is that possible?

Comment: The third callback function in subscribe is for [completed](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html)

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

You probably want to add a *debounce* to the `nr` stream. That way if the user types multiple numbers in rapid successsion, you don't send a request for each number. `debounceTime()` lets you wait for a set amount for milliseconds after a value is entered, if no new value is entered in that time, it's passed on. If a new value is entered within the set time, the time will be reset; rinse and repeat.

You should not do async work in the `subscribe()`, it "kind of" breaks Rx. All async work should be done before `subscribe()` inside another operator; very often one the `*Map()` operators.

---

I'm assuming `someMethod()` returns an observable (or you can probably convert it to one) and in that case you'll want the `switchMap()` operator. You return an observable inside `switchMap()` and it will only subscribe to the most recent observable. It will also unsubscribe from the previous observable.

```
let stream,
nr = document.querySelector('input').value
    .debounceTime(500); // This will wait 500 ms before passing on a value
                        // If a new value arrives before 500ms has passed, it resets the time

stream = nr
    .switchMap(num => someService.someMethod(num))
    .subscribe(clonedNr => console.log(`received response for ${clonedNr}`));
```